# Repeat a Retrofit2.0 api-call based on the server response

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

**Using Retrofit2 (Ver: 2.3.0), OkHTTP3 (Ver: 3.9.0) with RxJava2 (Ver: 2.0.0)**

Scenario of a rest api call

```
 Observable<ServerResponse> backendService.isUserVerified("someuserName")
```

which returns a **200 Ok** HTTP

Expected Success Response JSON POJO if user is verified

```
{

  user: "someUserName",

  isVerified: "yes"

}
```

Expected Success Response JSON POJO if user is not verified

```
{

  user: "someUserName",

  isVerified: "no"

}
```

Following is code I am trying to implement

```
 backendService.isUserVerified("someuserName")
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

  //Want to add a flatmap (or some other operator)
  .flatmap(new Function<ServerResponse>, ObservableSource<?>>(){
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<?> apply(ServerResponse serverResponse) throws Exception {
                if(0 != serverResponse.getisVerified.compareToIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                return Observable.error(new CustomException());
             }
             return //current observable.
  }

 .retryWhen(mRetryHandler)
 .subscribeWith(observer);
```

The intent is to throw a custom exception if verified == no so that retryWhen() operator can pitch in to repeat the call chain, else want to proceed through the chain till subscribe().

Any pointers / help ?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do? You want to replace `ObservableResource<?>` with what you want to continue with?

Comment: Yes ObservableSource for both error and fall through scenario...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`doOnNext`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) rather than `flatmap`:

```
backendService.isUserVerified("someuserName")
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

//we can throw an exception if the user is not verified or keep the response as it is otherwise
.doOnNext(serverResponse -> {
                        if(0 != serverResponse.getisVerified.compareToIgnoreCase("yes")) 
                        {
                            throw new CustomException();
                        }
                    })

.retryWhen(mRetryHandler)
.subscribeWith(observer);
```

The [`doOnNext`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) operator just performs a function with the emitted item without changing it. You just want to throw an error in a specific case based on the item and otherwise not to change it so it's an appropriate operator to use. As you don't change threads before the `doOnNext` operator or after it, before using the item in the next operator you know it will throw the exception BEFORE continuing in case it should throw it.

Here's an example from the linked documentation of the operator:

> ```
> Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
>       .doOnNext(new Action1<Integer>() {
>       @Override
>       public void call(Integer item) {
>         if( item > 1 ) {
>           throw new RuntimeException( "Item exceeds maximum value" );
>         }
>       }
>     }).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onNext(Integer item) {
>         System.out.println("Next: " + item);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onError(Throwable error) {
>         System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onCompleted() {
>         System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> [output:]
>
> Next: 1
>
> Error: Item exceeds maximum value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an error using `Observable.error(new CustomException());`, you don't need to make function to return a specific object for the error and another one for the expected answer, it's an exception and will go to `onError()` method. Your `ObservableResource<?>` must return your expected answer that is retrieved in `onResponse()` method from `Subscriber`. If you throw an error using `Observable.error()`, your chain will be broken and error will be go to `onError()`.

**Edit**

You should use `retry` function, because will return you `ServerResponse` and you can check if is valid or not. Using `retryWhen`, you get only the error when something goes wrong. In your case, you don't get any error, you get the answer. In this case, you don't need that `flatMap`

```
.retry(new BiPredicate<ServerResponse, Throwable>() {
           @Override
           public boolean test(ServerResponse serverResponse, Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
               return serverResponse.getisVerified.equals("no");
           }
     })
```

Comment: I guess you missed retry operator below in the chain... It will consume the exception thrown.

My question is exactly on how to create this observable.

Comment: Actually I need the api retry for both "getisVerified.equals("no")"  and as well as error-scenario.

Comment: You get both of them if you look closer at `retry` function from my answer.